# Tradingviewl strategy.entry add delay

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api

Good evening, I have a strategy and I am using it together with a bot, I need to delay the new position by a few seconds, so that the bot has time to finish the previous operation

```
// This source code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/
// © Guilomaker


//@version=5
strategy('Futuro Milhonario Sem Take', overlay=true)
Periods = input(title='Periodo ATR', defval=10)
src = input(hl2, title='Source')
Multiplier = input.float(title='Multiplicador ATR', step=0.1, defval=3.0)
changeATR = input(title='Alterar método de cálculo do ATR?', defval=true)
showsignals = input(title='Mostrar sinais de compra/venda ?', defval=false)
highlighting = input(title='Marcador On/Off ?', defval=true)
barcoloring = input(title='Coloração de barras On/Off ?', defval=true)
atr2 = ta.sma(ta.tr, Periods)
atr = changeATR ? ta.atr(Periods) : atr2
up = src - Multiplier * atr
up1 = nz(up[1], up)
up := close[1] > up1 ? math.max(up, up1) : up
dn = src + Multiplier * atr
dn1 = nz(dn[1], dn)
dn := close[1] < dn1 ? math.min(dn, dn1) : dn
trend = 1
trend := nz(trend[1], trend)
trend := trend == -1 and close > dn1 ? 1 : trend == 1 and close < up1 ? -1 : trend
upPlot = plot(trend == 1 ? up : na, title='Up Trend', style=plot.style_linebr, linewidth=2, color=color.rgb(0, 123, 9))
buySignal = trend == 1 and trend[1] == -1
plotshape(buySignal ? up : na, title='UpTrend Begins', location=location.absolute, style=shape.circle, size=size.tiny, color=color.rgb(0, 123, 9))
plotshape(buySignal and showsignals ? up : na, title='Comprar', text='Comprar', location=location.absolute, style=shape.labelup, size=size.tiny, color=color.rgb(0, 123, 9), textcolor=color.new(color.white, 0))
dnPlot = plot(trend == 1 ? na : dn, title='Down Trend', style=plot.style_linebr, linewidth=2, color=color.rgb(178, 40, 51) )
sellSignal = trend == -1 and trend[1] == 1
plotshape(sellSignal ? dn : na, title='DownTrend Begins', location=location.absolute, style=shape.circle, size=size.tiny, color=color.rgb(178, 40, 51) )
plotshape(sellSignal and showsignals ? dn : na, title='Vender', text='Vender', location=location.absolute, style=shape.labeldown, size=size.tiny, color=color.rgb(178, 40, 51) , textcolor=color.new(color.white, 0))
mPlot = plot(ohlc4, title='', style=plot.style_circles, linewidth=0)
longFillColor = highlighting ? trend == 1 ? color.rgb(76, 175, 79, 90) : color.rgb(255, 255, 255, 100) : color.white
shortFillColor = highlighting ? trend == -1 ? color.rgb(255, 82, 82, 90) : color.rgb(255, 255, 255, 100) : color.white
fill(mPlot, upPlot, title='UpTrend Highligter', color=longFillColor)
fill(mPlot, dnPlot, title='DownTrend Highligter', color=shortFillColor)
// BACKTEST DATE
Start_Time = input.time(defval=timestamp('01 January 2023 01:00 +0000'), title='Data Inicial', group = " ################# Data do Backtest ################ " )
End_Time = input.time(defval=timestamp('30 April 2024 19:30 +0000'), title='Data Final', group = " ################# Data do Backtest ################ " )

trade_direction = input.string(title='Direção', group = " #################  Configuraçoes  ################ ", options=['Long', 'Short', 'Ambos'], defval='Ambos')
long_comment_open = input('Long Aberto', title = "Rotulo Long", tooltip = "if you write your alert window this code {{strategy.order.alert_message}} .When trigger Long signal you will get dynamically what you pasted here for Long Open Message ")
short_comment_open = input('Short Aberto', title = "Rotulo Short", tooltip = "if you write your alert window this code {{strategy.order.alert_message}} .When trigger Long signal you will get dynamically what you pasted here for Short Open Message ")
long_comment_close = input('Take Long', title = "Rotulo TP Long", tooltip = "if you write your alert window this code {{strategy.order.alert_message}} .When trigger Long signal you will get dynamically what you pasted here for Long Close Message ")
short_comment_close = input('Take Short', title = "Rotulo TP Short", tooltip = "if you write your alert window this code {{strategy.order.alert_message}} .When trigger Long signal you will get dynamically what you pasted here for Short Close Message ")

long_message_open = input('long', title = "Gatilho Alerta Long", group = " #################  Alertas  ################ ", tooltip = "if you write your alert window this code {{strategy.order.alert_message}} .When trigger Long signal you will get dynamically what you pasted here for Long Open Message ")
short_message_open = input('short', title = "Gatilho Alerta Short", group = " #################  Alertas  ################ ", tooltip = "if you write your alert window this code {{strategy.order.alert_message}} .When trigger Long signal you will get dynamically what you pasted here for Short Open Message ")
long_message_close = input('close', title = "Gatilho Fechar Long", group = " #################  Alertas  ################ ", tooltip = "if you write your alert window this code {{strategy.order.alert_message}} .When trigger Long signal you will get dynamically what you pasted here for Long Close Message ")
short_message_close = input('close', title = "Gatilho Fechar Short", group = " #################  Alertas  ################ ", tooltip = "if you write your alert window this code {{strategy.order.alert_message}} .When trigger Long signal you will get dynamically what you pasted here for Short Close Message ")

Time_interval = time > Start_Time and time < End_Time
bgcolor(Time_interval ? color.rgb(14, 14, 14, 16) : na)



longCondition = buySignal

var ToLong = false
var ToShort = false

if ToLong and Time_interval and ( trade_direction == 'Long' or trade_direction == 'Ambos')
    strategy.entry('long', strategy.long, alert_message=long_message_open, comment=long_comment_open)
    ToLong := false
    ToShort := false

if longCondition
    ToLong := true
    ToShort := false
    
    if strategy.position_size < 0
        strategy.close('short', alert_message=short_message_close, comment=short_comment_close)
        ToLong := true
        ToShort := false



shortCondition = sellSignal
if ToShort and Time_interval and ( trade_direction == 'Short' or trade_direction == 'Ambos')
    strategy.entry('short', strategy.short, alert_message=short_message_open, comment=short_comment_open)
    ToShort := false
    ToLong := false


if shortCondition
    ToShort := true
    ToLong := false

    if strategy.position_size > 0
        strategy.close('long', alert_message=long_message_close, comment=long_comment_close)
        ToLong := false
        ToShort := true

buy1 = ta.barssince(buySignal)
sell1 = ta.barssince(sellSignal)
color1 = buy1[1] < sell1[1] ? color.rgb(0, 123, 9) : buy1[1] > sell1[1] ? color.rgb(178, 40, 51)  : na
barcolor(barcoloring ? color1 : na)
```

I need it to close the previous operation when opening the new heiken, and delay about 5 seconds and open the operation in the same heiken

in tradingview I leave it to recalculate after the order is executed, then it closes and opens the operation in the same heiken, I just need to delay the opening.

I've tried several things without success.

Answer (score 0):

Hope the modification of your script below solves your problem:

```
// This source code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/
// © Guilomaker


//@version=5
strategy('Futuro Milhonario Sem Take', overlay=true)
Periods = input(title='Periodo ATR', defval=10)
src = input(hl2, title='Source')
Multiplier = input.float(title='Multiplicador ATR', step=0.1, defval=3.0)
changeATR = input(title='Alterar método de cálculo do ATR?', defval=true)
showsignals = input(title='Mostrar sinais de compra/venda ?', defval=false)
highlighting = input(title='Marcador On/Off ?', defval=true)
barcoloring = input(title='Coloração de barras On/Off ?', defval=true)
atr2 = ta.sma(ta.tr, Periods)
atr = changeATR ? ta.atr(Periods) : atr2
up = src - Multiplier * atr
up1 = nz(up[1], up)
up := close[1] > up1 ? math.max(up, up1) : up
dn = src + Multiplier * atr
dn1 = nz(dn[1], dn)
dn := close[1] < dn1 ? math.min(dn, dn1) : dn
trend = 1
trend := nz(trend[1], trend)
trend := trend == -1 and close > dn1 ? 1 : trend == 1 and close < up1 ? -1 : trend
upPlot = plot(trend == 1 ? up : na, title='Up Trend', style=plot.style_linebr, linewidth=2, color=color.rgb(0, 123, 9))
buySignal = trend == 1 and trend[1] == -1
plotshape(buySignal ? up : na, title='UpTrend Begins', location=location.absolute, style=shape.circle, size=size.tiny, color=color.rgb(0, 123, 9))
plotshape(buySignal and showsignals ? up : na, title='Comprar', text='Comprar', location=location.absolute, style=shape.labelup, size=size.tiny, color=color.rgb(0, 123, 9), textcolor=color.new(color.white, 0))
dnPlot = plot(trend == 1 ? na : dn, title='Down Trend', style=plot.style_linebr, linewidth=2, color=color.rgb(178, 40, 51) )
sellSignal = trend == -1 and trend[1] == 1
plotshape(sellSignal ? dn : na, title='DownTrend Begins', location=location.absolute, style=shape.circle, size=size.tiny, color=color.rgb(178, 40, 51) )
plotshape(sellSignal and showsignals ? dn : na, title='Vender', text='Vender', location=location.absolute, style=shape.labeldown, size=size.tiny, color=color.rgb(178, 40, 51) , textcolor=color.new(color.white, 0))
mPlot = plot(ohlc4, title='', style=plot.style_circles, linewidth=0)
longFillColor = highlighting ? trend == 1 ? color.rgb(76, 175, 79, 90) : color.rgb(255, 255, 255, 100) : color.white
shortFillColor = highlighting ? trend == -1 ? color.rgb(255, 82, 82, 90) : color.rgb(255, 255, 255, 100) : color.white
fill(mPlot, upPlot, title='UpTrend Highligter', color=longFillColor)
fill(mPlot, dnPlot, title='DownTrend Highligter', color=shortFillColor)
// BACKTEST DATE
Start_Time = input.time(defval=timestamp('01 January 2023 01:00 +0000'), title='Data Inicial', group = " ################# Data do Backtest ################ " )
End_Time = input.time(defval=timestamp('30 April 2024 19:30 +0000'), title='Data Final', group = " ################# Data do Backtest ################ " )

trade_direction = input.string(title='Direção', group = " #################  Configuraçoes  ################ ", options=['Long', 'Short', 'Ambos'], defval='Ambos')
long_comment_open = input('Long Aberto', title = "Rotulo Long", tooltip = "if you write your alert window this code {{strategy.order.alert_message}} .When trigger Long signal you will get dynamically what you pasted here for Long Open Message ")
short_comment_open = input('Short Aberto', title = "Rotulo Short", tooltip = "if you write your alert window this code {{strategy.order.alert_message}} .When trigger Long signal you will get dynamically what you pasted here for Short Open Message ")
long_comment_close = input('Take Long', title = "Rotulo TP Long", tooltip = "if you write your alert window this code {{strategy.order.alert_message}} .When trigger Long signal you will get dynamically what you pasted here for Long Close Message ")
short_comment_close = input('Take Short', title = "Rotulo TP Short", tooltip = "if you write your alert window this code {{strategy.order.alert_message}} .When trigger Long signal you will get dynamically what you pasted here for Short Close Message ")

long_message_open = input('long', title = "Gatilho Alerta Long", group = " #################  Alertas  ################ ", tooltip = "if you write your alert window this code {{strategy.order.alert_message}} .When trigger Long signal you will get dynamically what you pasted here for Long Open Message ")
short_message_open = input('short', title = "Gatilho Alerta Short", group = " #################  Alertas  ################ ", tooltip = "if you write your alert window this code {{strategy.order.alert_message}} .When trigger Long signal you will get dynamically what you pasted here for Short Open Message ")
long_message_close = input('close', title = "Gatilho Fechar Long", group = " #################  Alertas  ################ ", tooltip = "if you write your alert window this code {{strategy.order.alert_message}} .When trigger Long signal you will get dynamically what you pasted here for Long Close Message ")
short_message_close = input('close', title = "Gatilho Fechar Short", group = " #################  Alertas  ################ ", tooltip = "if you write your alert window this code {{strategy.order.alert_message}} .When trigger Long signal you will get dynamically what you pasted here for Short Close Message ")

Time_interval = time > Start_Time and time < End_Time
bgcolor(Time_interval ? color.rgb(14, 14, 14, 16) : na)


delayTimeS = input.int(5, "Delay, s")
var delayTimeMs = delayTimeS * 1000

// there will be two states:
// 1. closeTime !> 0 - means that we have closed the trade and are will not open new ones until delayTime passes
// 2. closeTime == 0 - meanse that we are in trade now and should not open new ones 
varip closeTime = 1 // starting vale of 1 guarantees that first time we will enter the trade (timenow -1 is definitely > delayTime * 1000) 

longCondition = buySignal

var ToLong = false
var ToShort = false

// only enter new trade if delay has elapsed (timenow - closeTime > delayTimeMs) and not in trade (closeTime != 0)
if ToLong and Time_interval and ( trade_direction == 'Long' or trade_direction == 'Ambos') and timenow - closeTime > delayTimeMs  and closeTime !=0 
    strategy.entry('long', strategy.long, alert_message=long_message_open, comment=long_comment_open)
    ToLong := false
    ToShort := false
    closeTime := 0 // no new trades until close

if longCondition
    ToLong := true
    ToShort := false
    
    if strategy.position_size < 0
        strategy.close('short', alert_message=short_message_close, comment=short_comment_close)
        ToLong := true
        ToShort := false
        closeTime := timenow // trade closed, starting counting the delay



shortCondition = sellSignal
// only enter new trade if delay has elapsed (timenow - closeTime > delayTimeMs) and not in trade (closeTime != 0)
if ToShort and Time_interval and ( trade_direction == 'Short' or trade_direction == 'Ambos') and timenow - closeTime > delayTimeMs  and closeTime !=0 
    strategy.entry('short', strategy.short, alert_message=short_message_open, comment=short_comment_open)
    ToShort := false
    ToLong := false
    closeTime := 0 

if shortCondition
    ToShort := true
    ToLong := false

    if strategy.position_size > 0
        strategy.close('long', alert_message=long_message_close, comment=long_comment_close)
        ToLong := false
        ToShort := true
        closeTime := timenow // trade closed, starting counting the delay


buy1 = ta.barssince(buySignal)
sell1 = ta.barssince(sellSignal)
color1 = buy1[1] < sell1[1] ? color.rgb(0, 123, 9) : buy1[1] > sell1[1] ? color.rgb(178, 40, 51)  : na
barcolor(barcoloring ? color1 : na)
```

Comment: How could I adapt it to my code? can you help me? thanks.

Comment: Please see amended answer above.